# Avoiding empty objects in rails each while preserving ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following template is based off of the rails tutorial at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

I'm creating the "real_comments" inline to avoid an extra empty comment created by the form @article.comments.build however this causes an error as the comment id is missing when I try to delete it.

```
No route matches [DELETE] "/articles/2/comments"
```

Is it possible to strip out the extra comment created by build while maintaining the index for performing operations on the comment by id? I came up with the real_comments solution myself by playing around so I have no doubt I'm doing something very un-rails which is causing the issue

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @article.title %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @article.text %>
</p>
<%#How to copy an array in ruby %>
<% real_comments = @article.comments.map do |e|
  e.dup
end %>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :commenter %>
      <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :body %>
      <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>

<h2>Comments:</h2>
<% real_comments.each do |comment| %>
    <p>
      <strong>Commenter:</strong>
      <%= comment.commenter %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Comment:</strong>
      <%= comment.body %>
    </p>

    <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.article, comment], method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article) %>
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `persisted?` method to help you filter out records that have not been saved

```
<h2>Comments:</h2>
<% @article.comments.select(&:persisted?).each do |comment| %>

...
```

Comment: Thanks that helps in this case but is it not possible to create and manipulate a copy of the rails variables while preserving their keys?

Comment: @SMC Well, you can use `.clone` instead of `.dup` - it will copy id as well, but it is not good for perfomance and is not a rails way to handle things

Comment: @philvarg `@article.comments.where(nil)` should also work

Comment: Thanks it's good to know it is possible but I get your point about doing things the rails way